# How to add temporary colomn which is selecting within the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to show a table that will show one more column, that column contains select statement within the table, i cant explain well but the example is like this...

I dont know the query for this

```
grade table:                                                  
+---------------------------------+     
| ID     Name     grade   quarterID       
----------------------------------      
| 1     | A     |  85    |    1         
| 2     | B     |  86    |    1          
| 3     | C     |  84    |    1         
| 4     | A     |  90    |    2
| 5     | B     |  88    |    2
| 6     | C     |  81    |    2
```

My Expected output is:

```
+-------------------------+
| Name | grade   | grade         
---------------------------
| A    |  85     |  90
| B    |  86     |  88
| C    |  84     |  81
```

Comment: There are only 2 quarters in your sample do you want to show all 4 quarters(eventually). And can there be more than 1 grade per name in each quarter? And if there are more than 1 grade in a quarter which would you pick? BTW I am assuming the 2 columns represent 2 quarters - you don't actually say so? They may actually be the min and max grades in all 4 quarters.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) maybe you will get more answers... Maybe your intention is to show one column with the minimun grade and another colum with the maximum grade. If this is the case, please, you have to specify in the question by editing it. The clearer the question the better the replies.

Comment: Is that grouped by quarted?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using conditional aggregation

```
select name, max(case when quarterID=1 then grade end) as grade1,
max(case when quarterID=2 then grade end) as grade2
from tablename
group by name
```

Comment: thank you for response... it works

Answer (score 0):

use case when with aggregate fucntion

```
select name, max(case when quarterID=1 then grade end),
max(case when quarterID=2 then grade end) from t group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste the below code

```
SELECT Name,max(case when quarterID=1 
                     then grade 
                     else 0 
                 end) as grade,
            max(case when quarterID=2
                     then grade
                     else 0
                 end) as grade
FROM grade
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Though it's possible to move this way but I will prefer to use unique/meaningful names for column,table and aliases.

Comment: thank you for response... it works

Comment: I am glad it worked. If you think it's right solution then mark it as Answer